# Page has a @IonicPage decorator, but it does not have a corresponding "NgModule"

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I was working on page navigation in Ionic. After using `ionic serve`, I got this error:

`The Page with .ts extension has a @IonicPage decorator, but it does  not have a corresponding "NgModule"`.

Can anyone explain why I am getting this error.

Answer (score 18):

This is because the `@IonicPage()` decorator is for deep linking, this will register the page in **ionic's deep link system**.

You can remove the decorator if you don't want deep link on that page.

Or you can register that page in your `YOURPAGE.module.ts` with this code:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyPage
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(MyPage)
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    MyPage
  ]
})
```

You can find more information in the [docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/IonicPage/)

Answer (score 7):

I just removed the following attribute from the component page:

```
<!-- /src/app/pages/{page-name}/{page-name.ts} -->
@IonicPage()
```

Other ionic example pages don't even have it. Seems like the ionic CLI is outdated (I'm guessing you used that to generate the page component).

Comment: @IonicPage() is for deeplinking. If you want deeplinking in your app you need to do the ngModule thing

Comment: i want deeplinking for lazy loading but it is not working for me. any info ?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use deep linking first read the [API doc](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/IonicPage/)

and now let look at an example for adding a page with deep linking:

This is our src folder structure :

```
-src
 --app
 --assets
 --pages
    --home
       *home.html
       *home.scss
       *home.ts
 --thems
 *some file we not working with them in here
```

for adding a page use this command in your app folder :

```
$ ionic g page show
```

show is page name.
and now this is our src folder structure :

```
-src
 --app
 --assets
 --pages
    --home
       *home.html
       *home.scss
       *home.ts
    --show
       *show.html
       *show.scss
       *show.ts
 --thems
 *some file we not working with them in here
```

If now you run your app with below command in your app folder:

```
$ ionic serve
```

you get error like this :

> /path/to/app/src/pages/show/show.ts has a @IonicPage decorator, but it
>   does not have a corresponding "NgModule" at
>   /path/to/app/src/pages/show/show.module.ts

now you should make file named `show.module.ts` (in error it says) in show folder then our src folder structure should be like this :

```
-src
     --app
     --assets
     --pages
        --home
           *home.html
           *home.scss
           *home.ts
        --show
           *show.html
           *show.scss
           *show.ts
           *show.module.ts
     --thems
     *some file we not working with them in here
```

and this is the content of `show.module.ts` file :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {IonicPageModule} from 'ionic-angular';

import { ShowPage } from './show';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ShowPage
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(ShowPage)
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    ShowPage
  ]
})
export class ShowPageModule {}
```

Done.
run your app with `ionic serve` and the error is gone.

You can navigate to your new page with

```
goToMyPage() {
    // go to the ShowPage component
    this.navCtrl.push('ShowPage');
  }
```

[see doc for navigation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/IonicPage/).

Comment: if we cannot define the module name explicitly, it is really so awkward. Just because of that I won't be able to benefit lazy-loading for my current project. I don't want to do that much refactoring

Answer (score 2):

You have to make sure the module file name ionic is looking for matches the file name you have. 
I had the same problem because ionic was looking for "home.modules.ts" and I had "home.module.ts" (no s at the end), therefore ionic couldn't find the @NgModule decorator.

Answer (score 1):

in my case my file name was not in case sensitive i have **N**ews.ts & **n**ews.module.ts

now run fine

Answer (score 1):

When you add a page using Ionic CLI for example

ionic generate page newPage

then it automatically generates file newPage.module.ts and inside newPage.ts it generates a line of text as

@IonicPage()

Well, you must delete newPage.module.ts and delete @IonicPage() from newPage.ts

then open app.module.ts and add newPage inside declarations and entry components.

Comment: This is a very bad practice. Always use separate modules for pages for lazy loading. Otherwise the boot time will be huge for your app

Answer (score 1):

This issue may occurs when you're using angular 2+ naming conventions, where it's used to be like `my-app.component.ts`, updating to the ionic 3 naming convention `my-app.ts`, you'll be able to use the `@IonicPage()` decorator if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Today I had the same issue when generating a page. This didn't happen a few days ago.

I deleted the page's `NgModule` and then the `@IonicPage()` decorator, which restored functionality. A bit hacky, but it's up and running for now...

Answer (score 0):

In your .ts page add the following code, replace the word 'name' with whatever you name your page. Don't forget to add your new page in the app.module.ts page.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
selector: 'page-name',
templateUrl: 'name.html',
})

export class NamePage {
   constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because **@IonicPage()** decorator is utilized for deep linking and lazy loading, so to implement that, you need a dedicated module to load all the required components for that page. Take a look at the Ionic docs:

[@IonicPage API docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/IonicPage/)

Comment: So, what happens if you don't have any components decorated with @IonicPage()?

Comment: Nothing happens, the app is going to load all components at the app initialization. If you do an ionic serve and open dev tools, will see the components/files loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Using only:

```
import { IonicPage } from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage()

@Component({
  selector: 'page-abc',
  templateUrl: 'abc.html',
})
```