# IonicPage is not working

Tags: ionic2, ionic3

I am using instructions at [IonicPage Documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/IonicPage/)

But I am getting the following error:

> Error: /app/src/pages/subscribe-channel/subscribe-channel.ts has a
>   @IonicPage decorator, 
>       but it does not have a corresponding "NgModule" at /app/src/pages/subscribe-channel/subscribe-channel.module.ts

To be specific, I made the following changes prescribed in the docs:

1. added `IonicPageModule.forChild(SubscribeChannelPage)`
2. added `@IonicPage()` on the component i.e. `SubscribeChannelPage`

I am unable to share code sample, since it is part of the larger application.

A similar error is reported here: 
[Page has a @IonicPage decorator, but it does not have a corresponding "NgModule"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43428528/page-has-a-ionicpage-decorator-but-it-does-not-have-a-corresponding-ngmodule)

IonicPage is commented out in the answer suggested there to get rid of this error. However, I am trying to make use of IonicPage and would like to know how to make it work.

Here is `subscribe-channel.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { IonicPage } from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
    selector: 'page-subscribe-channel',
    templateUrl: 'subscribe-channel.html'
})
export class SubscribeChannelPage implements OnInit {

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

and here is `app.modules.ts`

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler, APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { SubscribeChannelPage } from '../pages/subscribe-channel/subscribe-channel';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    SubscribeChannelPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    IonicPageModule.forChild(SubscribeChannelPage)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    SubscribeChannelPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler }
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

@gerdi, suggestions in the answer helped in avoiding the compilation errors. However, the deep-link still does not work, it takes to default page.

FYI, the deep-link was working earlier with following code in `app.module.ts` . However, I am trying the IonicPage assuming it is a better option for future.

```
        IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {}, {
          links: [
            { component: SubscribeChannelPage, name: 'subscribe', segment: 'subscribe/:channelId' },
          ]
        }),
```

Comment: can you add subscribe-channel.module.ts file?

Comment: have you got it working?

Answer (score 4):

In order to use `@IonicPage()`, the *"component page"* that you add the decorator to needs to have a connected module.

The error you are getting is basically saying.

> You have added the @IonicPage() decorator but there is no associated module for this component. You need to include a subscribe-channel.module.ts file that declares this component in its own module scope.

So you need to add a `subscribe-channel.module.ts` which is the declaration of a module.

To better understand this you can go into your terminal and generate a new template and see the files that it adds

```
>_ ionic generate page foobar
```

Under the foobar folder, you will see 4 files one of them is `foobar.module.ts` which is the module declaration.

FYI: You need to change

```
import { IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
```

to

```
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
```

in the generated template. There still seems to be a few issues around this new shiny stuff

Comment: your answer helped in avoiding the error I reported in the question. However, the deep-link still does not work.  [link](https://example.com/#/SubscribeChannelPage)  takes to the default page.

Answer (score 0):

> However, the deep-link still does not work, it takes to default page.
>   FYI, the deep-link was working earlier with following code in app.module.ts . However, I am trying the IonicPage assuming it is a better option for future.

For deeplinking you have to now set it in `IonicPage()` decorator of your required [ionic page](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/IonicPage/).

Remove

```
links: [
            { component: SubscribeChannelPage, name: 'subscribe', segment: 'subscribe/:channelId' },
          ]
```

as this was before IonicPage was introduced in ionic 3.x

Try:

```
@IonicPage({
  name: 'SubscribeChannelPage',
  segment: 'subscribe/:channelId'
})
```

in **subscribe-channel.ts**.
Example Url will be:

```
 http://localhost:8101/#/subscribe/:channelId
```

Comment: This is mentioned in the IonicPage documentation, and I am trying the same. However, it is not working. Earlier I was facing compilation issues, which have been resolved as suggested by @gerdi. Still, I am not sure why the deep-link is not working.

Comment: https://github.com/mhartington/star-track-ionic/tree/master/src here is a sample project I found by mhartington. It implements what you are trying

Comment: Is it possible to have the same effect only without the # symbol?

Answer (score 0):

The file name of the module is the same as the component:
- `login.ts`
- `login.module.ts`
The module needs to be named `login` in order to correspond.