# Ionic 4 page has IonicPage decorator but not "NgModule"

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

**My ionic version:**

```
   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.2.1
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2 
    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0
```

**Error:**

```
Error: C:\...\src\pages\buyer-form\buy-sell\buy-sell.ts has
a @IonicPage decorator, but it does not have a corresponding "NgModule" at
C:\...\src\pages\buyer-form\buy-sell\buy-sell.module.ts
```

**Page:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {NavController, NavParams, ToastController, IonicPage} from 'ionic-angular';
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage({
    name: 'BuySellPage',
    priority: 'high'
  })

@Component({
  selector: 'page-buy-sell',
  templateUrl: 'buy-sell.html',
})

export class BuySellPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,
              public events: Events) {
  }
}
```

**Page.module:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';

import { ComponentsModule } from '../../../components/components.module';
import { BuySellPage } from './buy-sell';


@NgModule({
declarations: [
    BuySellPage
],
imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(BuySellPage),
    ComponentsModule,
],
exports: [
    BuySellPage
],
entryComponents: [
    BuySellPage
]
})

export class BuySellModule {}
```

**App.module:**

```
      ...
      imports: [ 
...
   IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
          mode: 'ios',
          preloadModules: true
        }),
...
    BuySellModule ]
      ...
```

I think I did everything right, declared `module` in my `app.module`, then in `page.module` declared `page` and in page wrote `@IonicPage` decorator. That `page` has his own module which declares page with : `IonicPageModule.forChild(BuySellPage)`.

**Whats the problem then ?**

*And no it's not duplicate question from -> [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43428528/page-has-a-ionicpage-decorator-but-it-does-not-have-a-corresponding-ngmodule), because I really did the same as the most answers.*